# .net maui keep keyboard open

Tags: .net, maui

I am working on an app that has functionality similar to a chat app.
I have an Entry where the user types their message.
When I press Return on the keyboard, focus leaves the Entry and the keyboard disappears.

If I call myEntry.Focus() in the Completed event, focus remains in the Entry, but the keyboard closes and opens again, providing a bad user experience.

How can I keep the on-screen keyboard open, cross platform?

Answer (score 0):

Despite all of the advice and examples regarding Even mappings, sub-classing, Message interception and Custom Renderers and Behavior customisation, nothing worked...

An excellent workaround is to use an Editor instead of an Entry, and use the TextChanged event to look for a NewLine character:

```
private void myEditor_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) {

    Editor editor = (Editor)sender;

    if (editor.Text.EndsWith(Environment.NewLine)){

        String text = txtChatInput.Text;
        txtChatInput.Text = "";
        
        DoSomeCoolStuff(text)
    }
}
```

The keyboard stays open, providing an great user experience.